# Running Ogre3D in Ubuntu error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, ogre3d

I have Ogre3D compiled and ready, the only issue is that when I go to test it, I get the following build output, and while it will compile, it simply just exits:

**Code**

```
Starting /home/holland/Code/C++/Test/ogreapp_build/dist/bin/OgreApp...
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group Internal
Creating resource group Autodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Font
ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
DDS codec registering
FreeImage version: 3.15.1
This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2,pfm,pct,pict,pic,3fr,arw,bay,bmq,cap,cine,cr2,crw,cs1,dc2,dcr,drf,dsc,dng,erf,fff,ia,iiq,k25,kc2,kdc,mdc,mef,mos,mrw,nef,nrw,orf,pef,ptx,pxn,qtk,raf,raw,rdc,rw2,rwl,rwz,sr2,srf,sti
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
plugins.cfg not found, automatic plugin loading disabled.
*-*-* OGRE Initialising
*-*-* Version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
An exception has occured: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'resources.cfg' file not found! in ConfigFile::load at /home/holland/Build/ogre/src/OgreMain/src/OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 83)
*-*-* OGRE Shutdown
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Compositor
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Font
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Unregistering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Unregistering ResourceManager for type Material
/home/holland/Code/C++/Test/ogreapp_build/dist/bin/OgreApp exited with code 0
```

I compiled the framework using a lot of the settings from [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Building+Ogre+With+CMake).

What the code is supposed to do is show a graphics renderer with settings, and then display a blank screen with fps data being displayed. The problem is that the code literally compiles, then exits.

**Question:** what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a `resources.cfg` file somewhere? It seems to think you should...

Comment: I do, and it exists. Is there something specific I should look for? It's in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/bin`

Comment: It needs to be in the same location as the executable you are running. It looks like you're running from the build directory, not the source directory.

Comment: I put it in as an answer so the question can be marked as answered. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resources.cfg` file should be in the directory where the executable is so it can be found.